# Trying to figure out how to use getCheckItemIds

Tags: android

I'm new to writing Android apps and would really appreciate some help with this:

I'm working on an app that allows users to select a set of tags from a series of check boxes using "CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE" - however I'm having a hard time figuring out how to save those checkboxes when the user clicks the save Button "save.setOnClickListener(onSave)"

I've read a bit about "getCheckedItemIds" but have had a hard time finding any concrete example of how it works and how it is used. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

I've attached my code below to give an idea of what I'm trying to do

```
public class PhysicsCollector extends TabActivity {

//EditText exampleName=null;

List<Example> model=new ArrayList<Example>();
ArrayAdapter<Example> adapter=null;

private ListView elementTags;
private String et_items[] = {"Friction", "Two Body Motion", "Constant Acceleration",
        "Newton's First Law", "Newton's Second Law", "Collision"
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    elementTags = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

    elementTags.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, et_items));
            elementTags.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    //exampleName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.exampleName);

    Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.example);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Example>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec.setContent(R.id.example);
    spec.setIndicator("List", getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.list));
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.details);
    spec.setIndicator("Details", getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.example));
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);

}

    private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Example e=new Example();
            EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.exampleName);

            e.setName(name.getText().toString());

            public long[] getCheckedItemIds ();

            adapter.add(e);
        }
    };



}
```

Below is the "Example" class which is used to save instances of the Array from the onSave:

```
   package org.encorelab.s3;

public class Example {
    private String name="";

    public String getName(){
        return(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return(getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Do you resolve your problem?? My regards